# Rails catch all route, excluding resources and HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, rails-routing

I am using Angular html5mode so have Rails routing set to redirect all failed requests to root

```
# Angular catch all to allow page refresh
get '*page' => "home#index"
```

This works just fine, except when an Angular module requests a missing template (/assets/templates/page.html for example), when it causes an endless loop

How can I tell Rails to catch all routes, **except** things in /assets ?

Answer (score 8):

I noticed this is quite old, but found it through Google and wasn't happy with the only answer here.  Since I worked through this myself I will share my solutions.

**Use the format parameter in your route**

```
get "/*path" => "home#index", format: false
```

Simply disable the format option for the wildcard path so it ignores requests with any format (e.g. css, js, png...)

---

**Use a constraint in the route**

```
get "/*path" => "home#index", constraints: -> (req) { !(req.fullpath =~ /^\/assets\/.*/) }
```

Specify a constraint option with a simple lambda checking your path value, not the best regular expression but shows the idea I'm going for here...

---

Personally I use the format parameter in my apps, the constraints option also lets you pass in an object, check out the rails guide for more info -> http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints

Answer (score 1):

The routes are evaluated top to bottom, so you can do the following:

```
# Catch all missing templates
get '/assets/templates/*page' => '/assets/templates/default.html'

# Angular catch all to allow page refresh
get '*page' => "home#index"
```

Missing templates will be caught by the first statement and all other missing routes will be caught by the second statement